# Using base layout elements from components

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to setup a base layout with components which have to be filled by child components.

To make it easy for collaborators i thought about using component directives.

Lets say i want to have a globally placed toolbar at my layout which i want to use for site specific functions and create a directive which can be used by any component.

I have a complete example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-layout

I placed an element within my base layout:

*./app/app.component.html*

```html
<header>
  <h1>My new App</h1>
</header>

<nav>
  <a routerLink="/home">Home</a>
  <a routerLink="/foo">Foo</a>
</nav>

<div class="app-toolbar">
  <!-- DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
  <!-- HAS TO BE FILLED BY CHILD COMPONENTS -->
  <span>TOOLBAR | </span>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="toolbar"></ng-container>
</div>

<main>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

I created a component with template:

*./app/directives/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.component.html*

```html
<ng-template #toolbar>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

I used it from another component:

*./app/home/home.component.html*

```html
<app-toolbar>
  <!--
  THIS SHOULD BE VIEWED WITHIN TOOLBAR OF APP COMPONENT
  -->
  <button>Do sth for Home component</button>
</app-toolbar>

<p>Home content</p>
```

This example ist not working, i created it after hours of trying to get something like this to work, just to show what i would like to have.
Maybe i'm thinking too complicated...

Is there a better way to do this or is there best practice for such approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want components to dictate what should be displayed in application layout?

Your approach won't work, because template variables do not extend between component boundries. So *ngTemplateOutlet cannot access the #toolbar variable declared in toolbar.component.

The correct approach to this problem is to create a custom structural directive.

Check out this presentation, done by  Alex Rickabaugh (angular core), about creating a left-nav component with content dictated by components.

- [Advanced Angular Concepts by Alex Rickabaugh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKbY1t39dHU&feature=youtu.be&t=1m32s)
- [Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/adv-ng-left-nav?file=app%2Fleft-nav.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what i was looking for.

My result: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-layout-working